# Virtual audio mixer on libVLC

Tags: c++, audio, core-audio, vlc, phonon

I have no experience in audio programming and I want to start with an audio player (C++, Qt, MacOS), that plays multi channel track on a multi channel audio card, multiplexing all input channels on all output.
Things, I need from a framework are:

- Decode popular audio formats (FLAC) and get PCM streams for each channel
- Query OS about currently installed audio cards and their capabilities (channel count)
- Actually mix and transfer sound between these entities
- VU Meter
- Better cross-platform

From what I've learned, `VLC` is a powerful media framework. But I haven't found info neither if it is sufficient for my task nor any good tutorial about it.
Alternatively, I consider using `Phonon` (it's default media framework in Qt) or `Apple CoreAudio API`. What suits better for this task? Is there any good tutorials on audio programming in general and using `VLC` and other frameworks in particular?

Comment: AFAIK, and most of what I know is `CoreAudio` API, which gives most robust and sophisticated level of audio control but doesn't support FLAC streaming on system level. To have FLAC support on system level [this extension](https://sourceforge.net/projects/coreaudio-flac/?source=typ_redirect) should be used. It uses _callbacks_ and _pull model_ of data processing. It is not a "media framework" in the sense of QuickTime or VLC. It is much more low-level. Further on, you don't have cross-platform compatibility.

Comment: Do you know any good tutorials about audio programming? I'm completely unfamiliar with it and I just don't know where to start from.

Comment: Depends on what you need. For `CoreAudio` [this one](http://www.informit.com/store/learning-core-audio-a-hands-on-guide-to-audio-programming-9780321636843). For audio programming in general [this one](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/audio-programming-book). There are few more. I must say, though, the topic is broad and there's no "instant success" if you want to write serious software. Beware, audio is **real time** and ear is far more discriminating than the eye. Most of the critical, high performance code is written in "plain-C".